# Order by nullable objects at end with linq dynamic core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic, nullable

I use the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to sort a list with expando objects at runtime dynamically:

```
var entities = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
var entity = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
//(....)
entities.Add(entity);
   
// sortQuery is a string/ example: "Identifier ASC, Name Desc" 
var sortingEntities = entities.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortQuery);
```

The sorting work fine but if the value of an object = null, than I want that the object sorted at the end:

Example:
I do a ORDER BY field ASC, it would give me:

- NULL
- NULL
- Identifier1
- Identifier2
- Identifier3

Is there a way with System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to achieve the following ordering:

- Identifier1
- Identifier2
- Identifier3
- NULL
- NULL

I try it with

```
var sortingEntities = sortEntities.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortQuery, new NullsAtEndComparer())



public class NullsAtEndComparer : IComparer
    {
        
private static readonly IComparer BaseComparer = Comparer<string>.Default;

        private readonly bool _ascending;

    public NullsAtEndComparer(bool ascending = true)
    {
        _ascending = ascending;
    }

    public int Compare(object? x, object? y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (x == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return _ascending ? BaseComparer.Compare(x, y) : BaseComparer.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

But it causes an exception:
[image]

How can I overwrite the IComparer in this method of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(
      this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      string ordering,
      IComparer comparer,
      params object[] args)
```

Comment: `OrderBy` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) which receives an `IComparer`. You need to define a custom comparer to "put" the `null` value to the end.

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for the answer. How can I do that? I have adjusted my question. I am using .Net 5.

Comment: I've checked your comparer with a string array and with a simple dictionary and in both cases they work fine. What is your question regarding that?

Comment: Can you please share with us the `sortQuery`?

Comment: @PeterCsala sortQuery is a string/ example: sortingQuery = "Identifier ASC, Name Desc,  (...., Props DESC/ASC)".  My comparer doesn´t work with object or Expando object...

Comment: Your code appear to be fine. What Dynamic Linq package are you using?

Comment: @NetMage System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. I think the problem is that the library not support the IComparer<TKey>? comparer like microsoft... But only IComparer without generic. I can not overwrite the IComparer: public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>( this IQueryable<TSource> source, string ordering, IComparer  comparer, params object[] args)

Comment: That isn't a package - there are lots of differing versions of it.

Comment: @NetMage https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: Examining the code, your issue is that your `NullsAtEndComparer` doesn't implement `IComparer` and so you are calling the overload that takes `params object[] args`. Try adding `,IComparer` to your comparer class. Your problem then will be your comparer takes `object` and it is being passed a different type, so you have to somehow create a comparer that is compatible with the types in `sortQuery`.

Comment: @NetMage yess that is the problem. I tried using IComparer but I don't know how to override the type object. Perhaps the library should be expanded to include IComparer <T>

Comment: I have adjusted my question/post

Comment: @NetMage i have now the solution:  public class NullsAtEndComparer : IComparer<object>, IComparer

Comment: Exactly. I didn't remember you were accessing properties that were always of type `object`. Inside `OrderBy`, the `IComparer` is cast to `IComparer<T>` where `T` is the type of the property you are sorting by, which is why you need both.

Comment: @NetMage oh sorry I see.. I didn´t describe the list that I sorted. I adjusted now the first lines of my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

```
list.AsQueryable().OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name))
```

Comment: I use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. I want sort many properties from many objects dynamically.